# Definite integral of the product of the PDF and the CDF of two independent RVs

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent (but **not** identically distributed) continuous random variables with supports $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $(0,\infty)$, respectively, and $\Delta$ be the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. I want to know $\Pr[(X,Y)\in\Delta]$. My attempt:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-u}f_X(u)f_Y(v)dvdu=\int_0^1f_X(u)[F_Y(1-u)-F_Y(0)]du=\int_0^1f_X(u)F_Y(1-u)du$$

but I am stuck at this point since $X$ and $Y$ are not identically distributed... Any hints?

Comment: You won't get any further without  more info about the distributions involved. Btw, the continuity of $X$ and $Y$ does not guarantee the existence of PDF's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info in your question we do not come any further than:

$$\begin{aligned}P\left(\left(X,Y\right)\in\Delta\right) & =\mathbb{E}\mathbf{1}_{\Delta}\left(X,Y\right)\\
 & =\int\int\mathbf{1}_{\Delta}\left(x,y\right)\;dF_{Y}\left(y\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}dF_{Y}\left(y\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}F_{Y}\left(1-x\right)-F\left(0\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}F_{Y}\left(1-x\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Also instead of $x,y$ we can use $u,v$ to denote the bounded variables (as you did).

---

The use of PDF's needs a justification.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I know that the PDFs exist, but not the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Do you know the PDF's? In that case working out of the (first) result $\int_0^1\int_0^{1-u}f_X(u)f_Y(v)dvdu$ in your question cannot be improved.